# Magento 2.2.2 Database install leads to error

Tags: database, installation, magento2.2.2

I'm using php bin/magento install to install a fresh DB (i've achieved this successfully several times with Magento 2.1.8)

Everything goes smoothly untill step 538. I get the following

```
[Progress: 538 / 913]
Module 'Magento_GiftCardAccount':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order.gift_cards' in 'field   
  list', query was: SELECT MAX(entity_id) as max, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (SELECT `sales_order`  
  .`entity_id`, `sales_order`.`gift_cards` FROM `sales_order` WHERE (gift_cards IS NOT NULL)  
   AND (`sales_order`.`entity_id` > 0) ORDER BY `sales_order`.`entity_id` ASC                 
   LIMIT 50000) AS `t`                                                                        



  [PDOException]                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order.gift_cards' in 'field   
  list'
```

Any tips?

Comment: Your table `sales_order`  has a missing column `gift_cards` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned `cache` and `generated` folder manually. It worked.